# Finding the formula of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In an Arithmetic series you know that  $u_{11} = 32$  and that $u_8 + u_{13}= 61$.

How can you find the 'formula' of this series?

Comment: without further information the answer is: not at all.

Comment: What is the general formula of an arithmetic series ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** We know that $u_n = a + bn$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.  So, from the information given, we know that
$$
a + b(11) = 32\\
[a + b(8)] + [a + b(13)] = 61
$$
Using these equations, how can we find $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see the equation in this question!

Comment: This equation isn't part of the question; it's something that you're presumably supposed to know about arithmetic sequences.  Similarly, every geometric sequence can be written as $u_n = ab^n$ for some $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $a_n=a_1+d(n-1)$

$$\begin{cases}
U_{11}=32
\\
U_8+U_{13}=61
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
U_1+10d=32
\\
U_1+7d+U_{1}+12d=61
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks alot! Funny how symbolics differ in diffrent parts of the world ^^

Answer (score 1):

$$u_{11}=32$$  $$u_8 + u_{13} = 61$$
Therefore, 
$a + 10d = 32$ --- I

and

$(a + 7d) + (a + 12d) = 2a + 19d = 61$ --- II

Now, 2 x eqn. I - eqn. II gives,

$(2a + 20d) - (2a + 19d) = 32 * 2 - 61$

Therefore, $d=3$
Hence, using I, we get, a = 2.
Thus, you now have the entire series there with you.

Comment: Yes indeed, i found the solution using the hints above, but thanks for confirming!